# jQuery if-else statment not working in toggle

Tags: jquery

this code toggle the side-bar but didn't show text 'show sidebar' or 'hide side bar'

```
var sAndw = $("#sidebar, #wrapper");
  $("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function() {
    $sAndw.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
    if ($sAndw.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
      $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
    } else {
      $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");
    }
```

Comment: move $(this) to a variable outside if block and see

Comment: Is that all your code? Missing closed brackets for `on`

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and CSS; without that we have little enough idea what you're trying to affect, which makes it very hard to offer practicable advice or suggestion. See the "[mcve]," and "[ask]," guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var sAndw = $("#sidebar");
      $("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function() {
        //$sAndw.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
        if ($sAndw.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
          $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");
            $("#sidebar, #wrapper").removeClass('hide-sidebar');
        } else {

            $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
            $("#sidebar, #wrapper").addClass('hide-sidebar');
        }});
```